# Add an item into an array of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here's the code:

```
const cart = {
  contents: [],
  addItem(item) {
  }
};
cart.addItem("laptop");
console.log("The cart contains:", cart.contents);
```

I want to obviously add the item "laptop" into the property "contents" of the object "cart" and for the console.log to display that information.  I think all I need is for the "addItem(item)" method to know WHERE ("contents: [],") exactly to add these items bc right now it seems like it points to nothing?  Any help would be awesome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your `addItem` method, do this:

```
 addItem(item) {
    this.contents.push(item)
 }
```

This accesses the object's contents via `this`, and adds the item to the array.

Comment: Thank you.  When executing the console.log command it displays "[laptop]' with the square braces around it.  Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @NickPurry that's just because it's outputting the entire array. If you want to output an array element at a certain position, do `cart.contents[0]`, or change `0` to another index if there are more elements.